# I can't open DVDs in VLC whenever I suspend my system, why?

Tags: suspend, vlc, dvd

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, so I hope not to get the same answer I've already read a couple times.

I know that DCD playback does not work with stock VLC; you have to install the restricted extras. so far so good, I did that and everything works fine.

But: I tend to suspend my computer, rather than fully shutting it down, because I don't like waiting that much. I also use a program to do timed suspends (qshutdown), so I can fall asleep watching a DVD and not have to worry about a running computer.

You maybe wondering why I'm telling this? here you are: almost every time, I wake my computer from suspend, I can't open DVDs in VLC (it works, if I open it without DVD menus, but then it crashes somewhere in the middle of the film). Is there a known solution to it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, someone posted the answer on Google Plus.

Micah Green (https://plus.google.com/u/0/102136182668884097283/posts) suggested that you install *libdvdcss*.

Tim Cummings (https://plus.google.com/u/0/104389497239909407158/posts) says that hibernating and suspending can cause odd behavior like this.